# Prove the equation has at least 3 roots

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Prove that the equation $$\ x^4 =  18 + \frac{1}{1-x} $$ has at least three roots.

How do I use the intermediate value theorem to prove this? Does it mean I just need to find three different values for which $\ f(x) = x^4 - 18 - \frac{1}{1-x} $ is positive and therefore it will have a root?

Comment: Not just positive: find three intervals where $f$ goes from plus to minus or the other way round.

Comment: $f(x)=1+x^2$ has three values where it is positive, but no zeroes. Clearly that is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$g(x)= x^5-x^4-18x+19$$ Since we are looking for solution of $g(x)=0$ and we have $g(-3)<0$, $g(0)>0$, $g(2)<0$ and $g(3)>0$ we are done.

Comment: but what about $\ x = 1 $ ? I mean in the original function $\ x = 1 $ is underfined and therefore $\ f(x) $ isn't continuous. isn't that a problem?

Comment: No, because my $f(x)$ is different than your. I have no problem with my $f$

Comment: Yes but then it's mean your conclusion aren't valid for my original $\ f(x) $ ? and btw how did you come up with the numbers -3, 0 , 2, 3 ? just randomly picked?

Comment: Why not? It is obviously that $1$ is not a solution to that problem. I reformulated you fraction equation to a polynomial equation (they are equivvalent since $x\ne 1$). Yes, just randomly try numbers around 0

Answer (score 1):

Using Descartes Rule of signs on the polynomial function

$$ f(x)=x^5-x^4-18x+19 $$

we see that there are two changes of sign, thus there are either two or zero positive roots. But $f(0)$ is positive and $f(2)$ is negative. So it must be the case that there are two positive roots.

$$ f(-x)=-x^5-x^4+18x+19 $$

has only one change of sign in its coefficients, therefore there is one and only one negative root of the polynomial $f(x)$.

Thus the equation has two positive and one negative solutions.